# FQL: how to use WHERE clause in array-type fields?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

i want to select some feed from **[stream](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/)** table. my problem is i just want results from specific 'text' in **action_links** fields..

**action_links** is field with array type.. i don't know how to use WHERE clause in that field..

how to do that?

i am use this query but fail..

```
$q = 'SELECT permalink FROM stream';
$q.= " WHERE filter_key='cg' AND app_id = 'xxxxxxx'";
$q.= " AND action_links.text = 'zzzzzzz'";
```

**EDIT**:
it imposible for now.. because Facebook not support that yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, since the operations you can use are:

> Other functions that are available are
>   `now()`, `strlen()`, `substr()` and
>   `strpos()`.

So basically most of them are for strings and not array.

One side note, `action_links` is an *array* and not *object*, so `action_links.text` is not correct anyway.

Comment: yeah.. i am actually already test square bracket (`action_links[0].text`) to get the value.. but error parse massage show up..

Comment: @JanuarC.Andaria: as I said, this is because it's not valid. What you have to do is *maybe* adding more filters and then search the data in your PHP code.

Comment: is there any solution today for this that you are aware of?